# Get PCRE2 capture group name -if any- associated to a capture group number

Tags: c, pcre

Once `pcre2_match()` is successfully executed I use [`pcre2_get_ovector_pointer()`](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html#SEC29) to get the `ovector` and then build a data structure containing (1) the matched string (using `ovector[0]` and `ovector[1]`); and (2) the matched capture groups (using `ovector[2*i]` and `ovector[2*i+1]`, for `i` in `[1..rv)`, where `rv` is the return value of `pcre2_match()`).

For each capture group number, I'd like to include in the data structure the matched string (no problem, that's in `ovector`), the length of the match (same, the info can be extracted form `ovector`), and, and this is the difficulty, the name of the capture group (obviously, only if the matched group has a name).

Helper functions are available to [fetch matched capture groups by name](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html#SEC35). In particular `pcre2_substring_number_from_name()` could be used to transform a capture group name into a group number (i.e name-to-number translation). What I need in the exact opposite behaviour: **given a group number, get its associated group name, if any, or NULL otherwise (i.e. number-to-name translation)**. I assume I missing something obvious here, but I'm not able to find a way to do that using the PCRE2 API. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

This is not the simple number-to-name API function I was looking for, but the following snippet from https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2demo.html contains enough inspiration to implement what I need :)

```
(void)pcre2_pattern_info(
  re,                   /* the compiled pattern */
  PCRE2_INFO_NAMECOUNT, /* get the number of named substrings */
  &namecount);          /* where to put the answer */

if (namecount == 0) printf("No named substrings\n"); else
  {
  PCRE2_SPTR tabptr;
  printf("Named substrings\n");

  /* Before we can access the substrings, we must extract the table for
  translating names to numbers, and the size of each entry in the table. */

  (void)pcre2_pattern_info(
    re,                       /* the compiled pattern */
    PCRE2_INFO_NAMETABLE,     /* address of the table */
    &name_table);             /* where to put the answer */

  (void)pcre2_pattern_info(
    re,                       /* the compiled pattern */
    PCRE2_INFO_NAMEENTRYSIZE, /* size of each entry in the table */
    &name_entry_size);        /* where to put the answer */

  /* Now we can scan the table and, for each entry, print the number, the name,
  and the substring itself. In the 8-bit library the number is held in two
  bytes, most significant first. */

  tabptr = name_table;
  for (i = 0; i < namecount; i++)
    {
    int n = (tabptr[0] << 8) | tabptr[1];
    printf("(%d) %*s: %.*s\n", n, name_entry_size - 3, tabptr + 2,
      (int)(ovector[2*n+1] - ovector[2*n]), subject + ovector[2*n]);
    tabptr += name_entry_size;
    }
  }
```